# Google App Engine Quota's

Tags: google-app-engine, quota, google-app-engine-python

I am planning to use Google Cloud Pub/Sub in my application. When I enabled the Pub/Sub Api in Google App Engine Project, it shows me 10,000 Publisher Operations and 20,000 Subscriber Operations per user. I am not using Google SignIn for my app. So, how will these quota's be judged?

Apart from this, my Google Cloud DataStore Api show's me a free Quota of 100 million request's per day. And as per documentation I can only perform 50,000 write operations, 50,000 read operations and 50,000 small operations in free app. How to understand both of them?

Comment: Hm, Pub/Sub is a another Google Cloud product, it's not App Engine (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/). App Engine quotas (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas) are per-app, not per-user. You might want to rephrase/edit your question?

Comment: Thanks Dan. I have rephrased the question.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Pub/Sub is a standard Google API from the list available [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/). Any API request is charged against the quotas for a project. Google APIs require a project parameter for all API requests, e.g., in the RESTful  API to [create a topic](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/topic/m/pubsub/v1/pubsub.projects.topics.create) project ID precedes the topic name. If an API has OAuth2 authentication enabled, it ensures only the user that have access to a project can make API calls.

For Cloud Datastore API, at present the requests are proxied through an App Engine version ah-builtin-datastoreservice (this implementation will change in future). So your API request will receive an error after the free quota is exhausted. This is irrespective of the 100 million quota available for Cloud Datastore API.